# How to make list of floated elements jump over centered element (spine align / center stamp)?

Tags: css, position, alignment, centering, jquery-isotope

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/XXu8G/

I want the elements to align to the center around the spine. Isotope jQuery plugin has a similiar functionality called spine align: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/spine-align.html but unfortunately it lists only one item on each side. I want to have multiple items on each side.

How can these be achieved without separate "left" and "right" divs?

Comment: you want all the items to align to the center?

Answer (score 2):

This code works in CSS3 browsers ([**see fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XXu8G/11/); note, in IE8 and under, and those others not supporting it, the `nth-child` would have to be replaced by a *class* on every element that needs to "hop over" the spine center). The `center-stamp` needed to be made part of the list to make it work right for me (but see optional solution below).

```css
#container {
    width: 380px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#items li#center-stamp { 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    background:red; 
    margin: 0 -240px 0 140px;
}
#items li { 
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    margin:10px; 
    float:left; 
    display:block; 
}

#items li:nth-of-type(4n) {
    margin-left: 110px;
}
```

### Optional Solution

If the `center-stamp` is purely presentational, it can be moved to a pseudo-element like so ([**see fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XXu8G/18/)).

```css
#container {
    width: 380px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#items:before { 
    content: '';
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    background:red; 
    margin: 0 -240px 0 140px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
#items li { 
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    margin:10px; 
    float:left; 
    display:block; 
}

#items li:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
    margin-left: 110px;
}
```

### More "Flexible" (Still CSS3) Solution

For the new requirement of flexible width and dynamic number of elements, there is still a pure CSS3 solution assuming the width of the elements is standard. It is done through judicious use of `@media` queries (probably best generated by a css preprocessor like LESS or SCSS), of which you need to put a practical limit on just how wide you want to go. [**Here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XXu8G/48/) and the css code from that:

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#center-stamp {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
}

#items {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#items li { 
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    margin:10px; 
    display: block; 
    float: left;
}

#items > li:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-left: 110px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 380px) {
    #items {
        width: 380px;
    }
    #items > li:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }    
    #items > li:nth-child(4n+3) {
        margin-left: 110px;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 520px) {
    #items {
        width: 520px;
    }
    #items > li:nth-child(4n+3) {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }    
    #items > li:nth-child(6n+4) {
        margin-left: 110px;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 660px) {
    #items {
        width: 660px;
    }
    #items > li:nth-child(6n+4) {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }    
    #items > li:nth-child(8n+5) {
        margin-left: 110px;
    }
}
```

**Note:** The key is to reset the width to the number of blocks allowed, then override the previous width's `nth-child` selector to put it back to `10px` margin, then set the new count for `nth-child`.

Comment: That's great, thanks for answering! Here's where it gets a bit trickier though: What if the container is 100% width and the number of items per row is dynamic? In addition to that I need the center-stamp to be position:fixed so only the items scroll but not the center-stamp.

Comment: @user1540416--the `position: fixed` is not an issue, as the code can be made to easily gap with respect to that. However, the 100% width (flexible width) and dynamic number of elements would not be solved by this solution. It requires you know the widths and number of elements on each side of the center point.

Comment: Yes you are right. I wonder if this could be done with some JS.

Comment: @user1540416--I'm sure JS could be made to produce a clean solution also. I have actually come up with a pure CSS method that works assuming you know the width of the item elements (and they are all the same). See my update.

Comment: @ScottS That's some interesting code right there! Thanks a bunch! I ended up using a more traditional way with just having left, center and right divs with CSS table-cell styling for better browser support and simple CSS2. I'll post a code how I did that soon.

Comment: @user1540416--Thanks. Of course, your more traditional method will not exactly answer the question you posted about "jumping" a center element.

Comment: Here's my 'traditional' non-CSS3 method: http://jsfiddle.net/xDPZ3/ - Note that IE7 and earlier does not support `display:table-cell` but this method still offers better support than CSS3 and is light and simple.